# C# Checking to see if files exist in folder

Tags: c#, foreach, ssis

I have a For Each Loop container where I process files that arrive nightly. I have three user variables defined: FolderPath ("I:\Data Analytics\Referral"), FileName (blank) -- read only variables, FileExistsFlg -- ReadWriteVariables. The first two are strings and the last one is an int. I have added "using System.IO;" to my Namespaces.The value for the FileExistsFlg is 0 -- the default value when I added the variable.

Here is my C# code:

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here

   String FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() 
                   + Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();

    if ( File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value = 1;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(FilePath); 
    MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"].Value.ToString());

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success; 
}
```

The task executes, but it always returns a value of 0 when in fact there are files. I'm using MessageBox.Show(. . . .) to test the script.

The code works correctly if I provide a specific file name in the variable, but the file names will change every day. If I leave the variable blank, then it returns 0.

This doesn't strike me as rocket science and I'm mystified why it keeps returning a false value.

Thanks.

Comment: And why are you surprised here? File.Exists wants a filename to check, if you don't provide a filename why do you expect it to return true? True for what?

Comment: check the directory exists, get file list count how much is in it?

Comment: Side Note: If you want a build a file path you should use `System.IO.Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Are you trying to check if a *folder* exists, rather than a file?  I guess it's not clear to me exactly what you're attempting here.  If the file name is blank then what file are you looking for?

Comment: `The code works correctly if I provide a specific file name in the variable` - Can you tell us the difference between the values at runtime for both scenarios?

Comment: Is it possible that `Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"]`does not contain the trailing backslash? Is the path shown by the messagebox really ok?
As Igor mentioned, you should combine the path and filename by `System.IO.Path.Combine`

Comment: @OP: What happens if you use `String FilePath = Path.Combine(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString());`  ?

Comment: All I am trying to do is to determine if there are any files in the folder, regardless of the file name. If there are files, I'll execute my data flow task. If there are none, I'll send an email saying as much.

Comment: Oh well, to see if there are any files, you don't need the file name: Only the folder name is required. Then you can do `bool anyFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("folder name").Any();`

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I'm pretty green when it comes to C#, so if I use your code, does this evaluate to true (if there are files) and if it does, do I incorporate that into my if statement that sets the FileExistsFlg = 1

Comment: Your `if (File.Exists(FilePath))` would become `if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString()).Any())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to get all the files from a folder. You can use [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) to do this:

```
  string mypath = "C:/myfolder/";
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(mypath);
```

You can then run through all the files like this:

```
   foreach(string item in files){

     if(item.Contains("my file name without the extension")){
        //Do Something
     }

   }
```

**-----------EDIT #1**

```
string mypath = "C:/myfolder/";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(mypath);
if(!files.Length == 0){

 foreach(string item in files){

   //Run rest of code using the item

 }

}else{}
```

the foreach statement's string variable contains the file path of the file.

**-----------EDIT #2**

If an error occurs at the first if statement saying that the **"!"** operator cannot be applied to integers, then instead put the foreach code into the else statement.

```
string mypath = "C:/myfolder/";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(mypath);
if(files.Length == 0){

 //do nothing. No files are in the folder.

}else{

foreach(string item in files){

   //Do something. Files are in the folder.

 }
}
```

From my understanding of the question, inside the foreach statement would be the code to process and archive the file. The string called "item" should contain the path to the file.

Comment: Pretty much, all I need to know is whether or not there are any files to process. If there are, then my flag value equals 1, if there are no files, then the value = 0. This will determine if my data flow task executes. The file names change daily. The only commonality is that they're CSV file.

Comment: Do you have a separate list of already processed files?

Comment: To help clarify, I only need to know if there are any files in the designated folder. I do not need to know their name. I just need to know if there are any. If there are files, the For Each Loop Container processes them in the DFT and then I move them to an archive folder.

Comment: Let me edit my answer to give you the right answer.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance, but when I type "if(!files.Length == 0), it says the operator ! cannot be applied to int. Another newbie question: is the if statement checking for no files? I assume that is the case when Length == 0. Now when you have "foreach(string item in files), would I then put in my statement Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"] = 0? Similarly, for the "else" part, is that on it's own line { Dts.Variables["User::FileExistsFlg"]=1
}?

Comment: I will make another edit explaining things.

Comment: The IF statement was originally NOT checking for 0 files. The ! operator reverses the if statement. Here is more information on the ! operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-

Comment: One last clarification, the foreach text isn't needed. I have a ForEachLoop SSIS container that will process the files and move them. The result I am trying to achieve is 1 for files that exist and 0 if there are no files.

Comment: Ok. Is your question answered?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: your welcome. Read the Help Center to learn how to ask a question. Your question was not very good, which is why you got -2 votes.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask